# Why does joining two shapes render the mirror modifier to work improperly?

Tags: modeling

Before joining, I can make a complete shape with the mirror modifier. After joining  the cone and a circle on the side, the mirror modifier no longer works. On previous attemps, it works; but now it just doesn't. I dont understand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe that depend on the order the objects are selected. Joining A+B (B active) or B+A (A active) won't give the same result if only one has a modifier. But you should provide more details to be sure of the cause.

Comment: Omg you're correct, lemon. I wish I could make you a lemon juice to return this favor. Thank you!